# Outlook 2010 VSTO AddIn: UI freezes randomly, while adding folders to PST asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

My C# VSTO Outlook 2010 AddIn adds hundreds of MAPI folders to an imported pst file asynchronously. (pst exists in Outlook foldertree)

Here is an example:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    ... //get pstStore
    var rootFolder = pstStore.GetRootFolder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
      var folder = rootFolder.Folders.Add("Test" + DateTime.Now.Ticks);
      Thread.SpinWait(1000); //emulate work
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
    }
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rootFolder);
});
```

The Outlook UI freezes randomly at `rootFolder.Folders.Add(...)` for 2-3 sec. Sometimes after 20, sometimes after 50 added folders.

Any help / tip will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expect your addin to stop working completely in Outlook 2013 or newer: OOM raises an error as soon as it detects that it is being called from a thread other than the primary Outlook thread. Note that this applies to the COM addins only as they run inside the outlook.exe address space. Out-of-proc access is always marshaled to the main Outlook thread by the COM system (but that defeats the whole purpose of using OOM from a separate thread).

Only Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) can be used on a secondary thread. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (it can be used from any language including C# - I am its author), its [RDO family of objects](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) can be used on secondary threads: store the value of the `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` property on the primary thread (it is `IMAPISession` MAPI interface), then on the secondary thread create an instance of the `RDOSession` object (that will initialize MAPI on that thread) and set the `RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT` property to the value stored on the main thread - this way the two will share the same MAPI session.

Off the top of my head:

```
object mapiObject; //on the class/global level
..
mapiObject = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
...
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
  Redemption.RDOSession session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
  session.MAPIOBJECT = mapiObject;
  Redemption.RDOStore pstStore = session.Stores["YourStoreName"];
  Redemption.RDOFolder rootFolder = pstStore.IPMRootFolder;
  Redemption.RDOFolders folders = rootFolder.Folders;
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
  {
     var folder = folders.Add("Test" + DateTime.Now.Ticks);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
  }
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folders);
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rootFolder);
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(session);
}
```

Comment: +1 for writing this detailed hint. I'm thinking of using c++/cli and IMAPIFolder::CreateFolder(..). If this fails, your answer will be accepted and i'll buy your Redemption library.

Comment: I managed to get it working with c++/cli and Extended MAPI. [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815501.aspx). The difference in speed is phenomenal. For everyone not familiar with managed c++ i recommend Redemption! Accepted Answer.